# React Native Navigator / Stack Screen Rendering Nothing

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, screen, react-navigation-stack

I followed the documentation for React Native Navigation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation), and have my program set up properly to the point where there are no errors. I even have an `<ErrorBoundary>` wrapper around that works. However, when there is no error and everything works as expected, I get nothing on my screen but whitespace. I have a component loaded into the Stack Navigator, but it is not rendering. Take a look at my `App.js` File...

```
export default function App() {
  
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  const TestPage = () => {
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'black'}}>SAMPLE TEXT</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'black'}}>SAMPLE TEXT</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'black'}}>SAMPLE TEXT</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'black'}}>SAMPLE TEXT</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'black'}}>SAMPLE TEXT</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  return(
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView>
{/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */}
          <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>

              <Stack.Screen name="/" >
                {props => <TestPage />}
              </Stack.Screen>

            </Stack.Navigator>
          </View>
{/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */}
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  )
}
```

Note that I don't believe this is due to the fact that I didn't explicitly create a HomePage, because if that was the issue I would receive an error message like I was before. It knows it should be rendering the test component, but nothing appears. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

There was nothing wrong with the Navigator or the Stacks, it was the **main View component inside of the App Component's return.**
The code looked like this...

```
return(
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView>
{/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */}
          <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
             // Other Stuff
          </View>
{/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */}
```

When it should look like this...

```
return(
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView>
{/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */}
          <View style={{height: '100%, width: '100%}}>
             // Other Stuff
          </View>
{/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */}
```

This is because the basemost `View` cannot have its style be flex, since it has nothing to be relative too, hence it needs to be made the size of the screen more explicitly.